# Referencing a template file in a code

Tags: vba, excel, templates

I'm trying to develope a system of code and files to compare test reports of different parts using graphs. I get a test report back for the tested location on a part, 4 per part, that looks like this. (This is 25603 rows fyi)
[image: Report]

When the testing software makes the report and this opens I have a Auto_Open macro that does the following: Saves 2 files, one is named based on whats in A1 (Location 1,2,3,4) and is saved in a folder for father data extraction,the other is a back up copy. Its then supposed to open up this template file called "FRF Data Graphs" which is a xltx.
[image: Template]

The code is then supposed to copy the many cells and paste in the FRF Data Graphs1. I use select case for each location, to tell the code to copy from here and paste in this sheet, 4 sheets 1 per location, if case "". Because i'm comparing parts and this macro runs each time a new report is opened I am using a shift right to the next empty section (part 1,2,3,4).

I'm getting 2 different error codes, first one only occurs when the graph is in the report. 
[image: error]

The second is Subscript out of range 
Both errors are at the same line of code, under where all the * are.

```
 Set Omega = Workbooks("FRF Data Graphs1.xltx").Sheets("Location 1")
```

So whats wrong with my code...? How do I reference the template file and can I not use data in cells that is used by a complex graph?

Code

```
  Option Explicit
Sub ExportSave()

Dim Alpha           As Workbook 'Template
Dim Omega           As Worksheet 'Template
Dim FileTL          As String   'Test location
Dim FilePath        As String   'File save path
Dim FileProject     As String   'Project information
Dim FileTimeDate    As String   'Export Date and Time
Dim FileD           As String   'Drawing Number
Dim FileCopyPath    As String   'FileCopy save path
Dim FPATH           As String   'File Search Path
Dim Extract         As Workbook 'File Extract Data
Dim locs, loc                   'Location Search
Dim intLast         As Long     'EmptyCell Search
Dim intNext         As Long     'EmptyCell Seach
Dim rngDest         As Range

With Range("H30000")
            .Value = Format(Now, "mmm-dd-yy   hh-mm-ss AM/PM")
        End With

FilePath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test"
FileCopyPath = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Backup"
FileTL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
FileProject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2").Text
FileTimeDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H30000").Text
FileD = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G3").Text
FPATH = "C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\FRF_Data_Macro_Insert_Test\"

Select Case Range("A1").Value

    Case "Single Test Location"

    Case "Location 1"

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileCopyPath & "\" & FileProject & Space(1) & FileD & Space(1) & FileTL & Space(1) & FileTimeDate & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileTL & ".xlsx"

            Set Alpha = Workbooks.Open("\\plymshare01\Public\Holiday\FRF Projects\Templates\FRF Data Graphs.xltx")



                    locs = Array("Location 1.xlsx")

                    Set Omega = Workbooks("FRF Data Graphs1.xls").Sheets("Location 1")

                    'set the first data block destination
                        intLast = Omega.Cells(Columns.Count, "1").End(xlRight).Column
                        intNext = intLast + 5 - (intLast + 5) Mod 5
                        Set rngDest = Omega.Cells(intNext, "A").Resize(30000, 3)

                    For Each loc In locs

                    Set Extract = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FPATH & loc, ReadOnly:=True)

                    rngDest.Value = Extract.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A30000", "D3:D30000").Value

                    Extract.Close False

                    Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 3) 'move over to the right 3 cols

                    Next loc

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Case "Location 2"
    Case "Location 3"
    Case "Location 4"
    Case Else

        MsgBox "Export Failed!"

    End Select


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   End Sub
```

Comment: You are dimming Omega as `Workbook` and then setting it as `Sheet`

Comment: changed workbook to worksheet, same error, I think im not referencing the template right. When a name.xltx file opens its name1. How do I reference it? is it just name.xlsx?

Comment: I would advise to do the following: at the top of your code (all the way) put `Option Explicit` this makes you define every single object/string etc.. I notice you are referencing to things that I don't see being dimmed. After this see if it still throws the same error

Comment: Very helpful, I didn't realize i had so many mistakes... Fixed them all, updated above. Still throws the same code, same line

Comment: OK good :), you can also in Extra -> Options -> Editor check the box declare variables required <- this will put `Option Explicit` in every module you create from that moment. Besides that: You Set Omega as Workbooks("FRF Data Graphs1.xls").Sheets("Location 1") < is this workbook even open? As you open FRF Data Graphs.xltx not 1.xls?

Comment: Well the template file is named FRF Data Graphs (Alpha), but because its a template file xlfx it opens as FRF Data Graph1. So I'm not sure how to reference it in the code

Comment: Ah, i missed that part, so it opens with 1 at the end. but its a `.xltx` file thus the corresponding file type is `.xlsx` not `.xls`

Comment: `Set Omega = Workbooks("FRF Data Graphs1.xlsx").Sheets("Location 1")` Same error

Comment: Could you upload the file for me to look at?

Comment: use [www.wetransfer.com](http://www.wetransfer.com) to upload then post the link in your question as an update

Comment: yeah so my company blocks that site..

Comment: I would suggest to check which site you can upload to and do it from there. There are many uploading sites where you can store your file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88203/discussion-between-duraholiday-and-dragonsamu).

Comment: Let me know if everything is ok now

Comment: Its not liking a couple of things... I am breaking it apart. With what you gave me its giving me  Error '9' Subscript out of range for the `Set wbMain = Workbooks("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")' If I Dim wbMain as Workbooks instead of Workbook it passes that line and errors out at the next line.             ``wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy`` Method or data member not found. high lights Sheet

Comment: I will send you the file back then as it works fine inside the file i got from you and adjusted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following problems were in your code:

```
Set Omega = Workbooks("FRF Data Graphs1.xls").Sheets("Location 1")
```

This gives an error as the `.xltx` file opens a new template and Excel doesn't give a File Type extension until its saved. Also the `Sheets("Location 1")` reference was not correct, it should have been `Sheets("Location1 Raw Data")`.

The solution:

```
Set Omega = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Sheets("Location1 Raw Data")
```

This resolves the correct naming, and each time a new instance is opened by Excel (and Excel is still open) it will get a new number thus the reference to 1 would become useless.

The second problem is created by your `.SaveAs` this saves the workbook but the original workbook is not open anymore and because later on you open the `Location 1.xlsx` file read only your code stops.

to solve this you `.Copy`  the `Sheet` and save it.

Code:

```
Set wbMain = Workbooks("FRF Data Export Graphs.xlsm")
wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileCopyPath & "\" & FileProject & Space(1) & FileD & Space(1) & FileTL & Space(1) & FileTimeDate & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileTL & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

You will also need to define `dim wbMain as Workbook`
This `.Copy`'s the workbook and closes it after saving.

The final problem (assuming the Template is always empty)is setting your `rngDest` since its always a new template there is no need to find an empty range.

```
Set rngDest = Omega.Cells(3, 1).Resize(30000, 3)
```

This will do the trick.